# Create Tickets in autotask using REST api in python

Tags: python-3.x, api, rest

I am new to autotask.
I have taken the Resource location "15" from the below page on autotask because while creating the api user I have selected the location as "Headquarters".

[image]

I am trying to create a ticket in autotask using the below python code:
import requests

```
USERNAME = "xyz@abcsandbox.com"
PASSWORD = "xyz123"
TRACKING_IDENTIFIER = "XXXXXXXX"

REST_URL = "https://webservices15.autotask.net/atservicesrest/v1.0/Tickets"

headers = {'TrackingIdentifier': TRACKING_IDENTIFIER}
response = requests.request(method='POST', url=REST_URL, headers=headers, data={"AccountId": "12345678", "ContactId": "0000001", "DueDateTime": "2021-03-20 00:01:00", "QueueId": "12345678", "Title": "Some title here", "Status": "21", "Priority": "3", "Source": "-2", "TicketType": "4", "IssueType": "21", "SubIssueType": "303", "Description": "Description of ticket", "AssignedResourceID": "12345678", "AssignedResourceRoleID": "23456789"}, auth=(USERNAME, PASSWORD), timeout=1200, verify=False)

print(response.status_code)
```

The status code getting printed here is 401! What could be the reason?

Comment: Read the instructions and follow the path. Don't assume anything incl. the URL but request it using https://webservices.autotask.net/atservicesrest/v1.0/zoneInformation?user=<username>

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
USERNAME = "USERNAME_KEY"
PASSWORD = "PASSWORD_KEY"
TRACKING_IDENTIFIER = "YOUR_TRACKING_IDENTIFIER"

url = "https://webservices15.autotask.net/atservicesrest/v1.0/Tickets"

headers = {
        "username": USERNAME,
        "password": PASSWORD,
        "integrationCode": TRACKING_IDENTIFIER,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
response = requests.request(method='POST', url=url, headers=headers, data= 
{"AccountId": "12345678", "ContactId": "0000001", "DueDateTime": "2021-03-20 
  00:01:00", "QueueId": "12345678", "Title": "Some title here", "Status": "21", 
  "Priority": "3", "Source": "-2", "TicketType": "4", "IssueType": "21", 
  "SubIssueType": "303", "Description": "Description of ticket", 
  "AssignedResourceID": "12345678", "AssignedResourceRoleID": "23456789"}, 
   timeout=1200, verify=False)
print(response.status_code)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?